# inner join check all the rows?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Table1

```
id name
1  test
2  test2
3  test3
4  test4
```

Table2

```
id total
1   40%
4   80%
```

If we use inner join for these table,
Is join checking all the rows and finally return matched row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer yes. This will fetch for example (`join table2 using(id)`) test 40% and test4 80%)

Answer (score 1):

INNER JOIN match the result which are in table a and table b

Return rows when there is at least one match in both tables

**here an example of joins**

[image]

EDIT .

in your example by using **ineer join**

```
   select * from table1 t1
   inner join table2 t2
   on t1.id=t2.id
```

you will get result:

```
  ID    NAME    TOTAL
   1    test    40%
   4    test4   80%
```

by using **left join**

```
    select * from table1 t1
    left join table2 t2
    on t1.id=t2.id
```

the result is

```
 ID     NAME    TOTAL
  1     test    40%
  2     test2   (null)
  3     test3   (null)
  4     test4   80%
```

Comment: I think inner join fetch all the rows for relation comparison and return only matched rows. This what my question.sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You would use an outer join if you needed this:

```
1 test   40%
2 test1
3 test2
4 test3  80%
```

i.e. you want to join the tables on their id fields but see all of the information from both tables

Comment: I think inner join fetch all the rows for relation comparison and return only matched rows. This what my question.sorry for misunderstanding.